# removeOverlay:overlay not working

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm a new guy in the XCode realm and was wondering if someone could help me out.

Essentially, I'm playing around with WWDC2010's TileMap project example and am trying to figure out a way to hide their NOAA chart using a segmented controller.

I can activate the overlay and it displays fine, but I can't for the life of me remove it using a segmented controller.

Here's some code from the header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *controller;
}    
- (IBAction)switchMap:(id)sender;
@end
```

and here's the code for the .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    NSLog(@"initial view loaded"); 
}  

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay {  

    TileOverlayView *view = [[TileOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];     
    view.tileAlpha = 1;
    return view;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:     (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)switchMap:(id)overlay {

    if (controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"welp... it loaded...");
        [map removeOverlay:overlay];
    }

    if (controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        NSLog(@"Map Overlay works");
        NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
        TileOverlay *overlay = [[TileOverlay alloc] initWithTileDirectory:tileDirectory];
        [map addOverlay:overlay];

        MKMapRect visibleRect = [map mapRectThatFits:overlay.boundingMapRect];
        visibleRect.size.width /= 2;
        visibleRect.size.height /= 2;
        visibleRect.origin.x += visibleRect.size.width / 2;
        visibleRect.origin.y += visibleRect.size.height / 2;
        map.visibleMapRect = visibleRect;

    }


    if (controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"But... overlay isnt hiding waa");
        NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
        TileOverlay *overlay = [[TileOverlay alloc] initWithTileDirectory:tileDirectory];
        [map removeOverlay:overlay]; }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a control action method, the first parameter (no matter what you name it) is always the object that called the method.

Here, the control is a `UISegmentedControl` so the parameter that gets passed to `switchMap:` is a reference to that control.  In the .h you've declared the parameter with the name `sender` but in the .m it's named `overlay`.

Regardless of the name, it's still the segmented control object so passing it to `removeOverlay` is meaningless and will do nothing.

So in this code:

```
if (controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"welp... it loaded...");
    [map removeOverlay:overlay];
}
```

`overlay` is pointing to the segmented control and so the `removeOverlay` does nothing.

In this code:

```
if (controller.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
    NSLog(@"But... overlay isnt hiding waa");
    NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
    TileOverlay *overlay = [[TileOverlay alloc] initWithTileDirectory:tileDirectory];
    [map removeOverlay:overlay]; }
```

You are creating a *new* local `overlay` object (the compiler is also probably giving you a warning about a local variable hiding the parameter).  This new object is separate from the overlay that was already added to the map.  Calling `removeOverlay` on this new object does nothing because this new instance was never added to the map in the first place.

To remove an existing overlay, you either have to keep an ivar reference to it when you add it and pass that ivar to remove or find it in the map view's `overlays` array.

However, if you will ever have only one overlay, you can pass the first object in the map view's `overlays` array or just call `removeOverlays` (plural) and pass the whole array:

```
if (map.overlays.count > 0)
    [map removeOverlay:[map.overlays objectAtIndex:0]];

//OR...

if (map.overlays.count > 0)
    [map removeOverlays:map.overlays];
```

Comment: Thanks Anna, that cleared up a lot for me. I'm still new to all this and this response not only answered my question, but I learned a lot from it as well. Thanks!